# cross product of two vectors(rows) in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin

I tried to calculate cross product of two vectors in postgresql.
illustrations:
input:

```
edgex edgey edgez
6.80837996699847 39.4163159399759 0
0 0 12
```

cross product these two rows(vectors) in postgresql by using query

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working? The basic idea of a cross product is `(a2b3 - a3b2, a3b1 - a1b3, a1b2 - a2b1)` which is fairly trivial to calculate in SQL

Comment: ya,.. but i want to try in postgresql.. its in rowwise not columnwise

Comment: There is no direct type for a 3d point / vector in PostgreSQL. `point`  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html is 2d, `cube` (contrib module) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/cube.html use n dimension (but does not interpret it as a vector): both lack functions/operators to calculate any kind of vector products. You need to use its formula.

Comment: Homework / exam question?

Comment: @pozs, there is support for 3D objects in Postgis, though.

Comment: So give us your example query and where you would like to apply the cross product :)

Comment: @JohnBarça i see, it is implemented in `c++`, but not sure if it can be called on `SQL` level though http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.2/d2/ddd/lwgeodetic_8c_ab49bfa54fdded3ab7135b890d977cebf.html

Comment: @pozs. You may be right, I misread the original question. Thanks for that link, I haven't seen that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function for it. Assuming these are 3D point PostGIS geometries:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_CrossProduct(point_a geometry, point_b geometry)
  RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(
  a2 * b3 - a3 * b2,
  a3 * b1 - a1 * b3,
  a1 * b2 - a2 * b1), ST_SRID($1))
FROM (SELECT
  ST_X($1) AS a1, ST_Y($1) AS a2, COALESCE(ST_Z($1), 0.0) AS a3,
  ST_X($2) AS b1, ST_Y($2) AS b2, COALESCE(ST_Z($2), 0.0) AS b3
) AS f$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Use it:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_CrossProduct(
     ST_MakePoint(6.80837996699847, 39.4163159399759, 0),
     ST_MakePoint(0, 0, 12)));

                   st_astext                    
------------------------------------------------
 POINT Z (472.995791279711 -81.7005596039816 0)
(1 row)
```